# Cumsum reset at certain values

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
    x          y    count
1   1 2018-02-24 4.031540
2   2 2018-02-25 5.244303
3   3 2018-02-26 5.441465
4  NA 2018-02-27 4.164104
5   5 2018-02-28 5.172919
6   6 2018-03-01 5.591410
7   7 2018-03-02 4.691716
8   8 2018-03-03 5.465360
9   9 2018-03-04 3.269378
10 NA 2018-03-05 5.300679
11 11 2018-03-06 5.489664
12 12 2018-03-07 4.423334
13 13 2018-03-08 3.808764
14 14 2018-03-09 6.450136
15 15 2018-03-10 5.541785
16 16 2018-03-11 4.762889
17 17 2018-03-12 5.511649
18 18 2018-03-13 6.795386
19 19 2018-03-14 6.615762
20 20 2018-03-15 4.749151
```

I want to take the `cumsum` of the count column, but I want the the `cumsum` to restart when the x value is `NA`.  I've tried the following:

`df$cum_sum <- ifelse(is.na(df$x) == FALSE, cumsum(df$count), 0)`

```
    x          y    count    cum_sum
1   1 2018-02-24 4.031540   4.031540
2   2 2018-02-25 5.244303   9.275843
3   3 2018-02-26 5.441465  14.717308
4  NA 2018-02-27 4.164104   0.000000
5   5 2018-02-28 5.172919  24.054331
6   6 2018-03-01 5.591410  29.645741
7   7 2018-03-02 4.691716  34.337458
8   8 2018-03-03 5.465360  39.802817
9   9 2018-03-04 3.269378  43.072195
10 NA 2018-03-05 5.300679   0.000000
11 11 2018-03-06 5.489664  53.862538
12 12 2018-03-07 4.423334  58.285871
13 13 2018-03-08 3.808764  62.094635
14 14 2018-03-09 6.450136  68.544771
15 15 2018-03-10 5.541785  74.086556
16 16 2018-03-11 4.762889  78.849445
17 17 2018-03-12 5.511649  84.361094
18 18 2018-03-13 6.795386  91.156480
19 19 2018-03-14 6.615762  97.772242
20 20 2018-03-15 4.749151 102.521394
```

The result is the cum_sum column is 0 at the NA values, but the cumsum doesn't reset.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution:

```
dat$cum_sum <- ave(dat$count, cumsum(is.na(dat$x)), FUN = cumsum)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dat
>     x          y    count   cum_sum
> 1   1 2018-02-24 4.031540  4.031540
> 2   2 2018-02-25 5.244303  9.275843
> 3   3 2018-02-26 5.441465 14.717308
> 4  NA 2018-02-27 4.164104  4.164104
> 5   5 2018-02-28 5.172919  9.337023
> 6   6 2018-03-01 5.591410 14.928433
> 7   7 2018-03-02 4.691716 19.620149
> 8   8 2018-03-03 5.465360 25.085509
> 9   9 2018-03-04 3.269378 28.354887
> 10 NA 2018-03-05 5.300679  5.300679
> 11 11 2018-03-06 5.489664 10.790343
> 12 12 2018-03-07 4.423334 15.213677
> 13 13 2018-03-08 3.808764 19.022441
> 14 14 2018-03-09 6.450136 25.472577
> 15 15 2018-03-10 5.541785 31.014362
> 16 16 2018-03-11 4.762889 35.777251
> 17 17 2018-03-12 5.511649 41.288900
> 18 18 2018-03-13 6.795386 48.084286
> 19 19 2018-03-14 6.615762 54.700048
> 20 20 2018-03-15 4.749151 59.449199
> ```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(is.na(x))) %>% 
  mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(count)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: `cumsum(is.na(x))` is very clever to group the observations

Comment: This just sorted a headache of a problem I had, so thank you, Jaap!

Comment: how comes this dplyr solution is so much faster than looping

Comment: The dplyr version is very elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the data.table version

```
 plouf <- setDT(df)
 plouf[,group := cumsum(is.na(x))]
 plouf[!is.na(x),cum_sum := cumsum(count),by = group]

     x          y    count group   cum_sum
 1:  1 2018-02-24 4.031540     0  4.031540
 2:  2 2018-02-25 5.244303     0  9.275843
 3:  3 2018-02-26 5.441465     0 14.717308
 4: NA 2018-02-27 4.164104     1        NA
 5:  5 2018-02-28 5.172919     1  5.172919
 6:  6 2018-03-01 5.591410     1 10.764329
 7:  7 2018-03-02 4.691716     1 15.456045
 8:  8 2018-03-03 5.465360     1 20.921405
 9:  9 2018-03-04 3.269378     1 24.190783
10: NA 2018-03-05 5.300679     2        NA
11: 11 2018-03-06 5.489664     2  5.489664
12: 12 2018-03-07 4.423334     2  9.912998
13: 13 2018-03-08 3.808764     2 13.721762
14: 14 2018-03-09 6.450136     2 20.171898
15: 15 2018-03-10 5.541785     2 25.713683
16: 16 2018-03-11 4.762889     2 30.476572
17: 17 2018-03-12 5.511649     2 35.988221
18: 18 2018-03-13 6.795386     2 42.783607
19: 19 2018-03-14 6.615762     2 49.399369
20: 20 2018-03-15 4.749151     2 54.148520
```