# How to determine number of sequential true values in a data frame in R using tidyverse/dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and would like to add a column with the number of successive `TRUE` values using tidyverse.

For example, the following data frame:

```
dftmp <- data.frame(order = 1:10,
                    true = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

which looks like

```
   order  true
1      1 FALSE
2      2  TRUE
3      3  TRUE
4      4  TRUE
5      5 FALSE
6      6 FALSE
7      7  TRUE
8      8 FALSE
9      9  TRUE
10    10  TRUE
```

and would like it to look like

```
   order  true count
1      1 FALSE     0
2      2  TRUE     1
3      3  TRUE     2
4      4  TRUE     3
5      5 FALSE     0
6      6 FALSE     0
7      7  TRUE     1
8      8 FALSE     0
9      9  TRUE     1
10    10  TRUE     2
```

I can figure out how to do it in a loop (below), but not sure if there is a tidyverse equivalent (I suspect it will be with dplyr, but not sure)?

```
dftmp$count <- NA

for (lpVar in 1:nrow(dftmp)) {
  dftmp$count[lpVar] <- ifelse(test = dftmp$true[lpVar],
                               yes = dftmp$count[lpVar - 1] + 1,
                               no = 0)
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It'll be hard to beat the top-voted answer to this question for pure speed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012516/create-counter-within-consecutive-runs-of-certain-values

Comment: `dftmp$count <- sequence(rle(as.character(dftmp$true))$lengths) * dftmp$true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `hutilscpp` has a convenient `cumsum_reset` function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(hutilscpp)

dftmp %>%
  mutate(count = cumsum_reset(true))

   order  true count
1      1 FALSE     0
2      2  TRUE     1
3      3  TRUE     2
4      4  TRUE     3
5      5 FALSE     0
6      6 FALSE     0
7      7  TRUE     1
8      8 FALSE     0
9      9  TRUE     1
10    10  TRUE     2
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```r
dftmp %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!true)) %>% 
  mutate(cum_sum = cumsum(true)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

Credits for the second solution:

[Cumsum reset at certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953352/cumsum-reset-at-certain-values)